# Visa for participating in Paris 2024 Olympics games

Tags: visa

[French consulate](https://in.ambafrance.org/Contact-us-visa-queries)

What will be the visa required for Indians competing in the Paris Olympics games 2024? Is it a tourist visa, a skilled professional visa in sports, or some other visa type?Reference:

Comment: See https://www.insidethegames.biz/articles/1129508/paris-2024-visas for a report about an Olympic visa to be created

Comment: If you are participating as a sportperson, you can very likely expect your delegation to deal with formalities in bulk

Comment: This belongs on [Travel.SE].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schengen short-term visas are not issued in different classes.  The application asks the applicant to indicate the purpose of the trip, choosing one of *Tourism, Business, Visiting family or friends, Cultural, Sports, Official visit, Medical reasons, Study, Airport transit,* and *Other (please specify).*  The only one of these choices that leads to a different class of visa is *airport transit.*

For an Olympic athlete, the obvious selection is *sports.*  On top of this, the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20200202) has a whole annex, Annex XI, devoted to procedures for issuing visas to Olympic participants.  It provides, among other things, for the collective processing of visa applications and for their collective submission by participating organizations:

> 1. Where a responsible organisation draws up a list of the persons selected to take part in the Olympic and/or Paralympic Games, it may, together with the application for the issue of an Olympic accreditation card for the persons selected, file a collective application for visas for those persons selected who are required to be in possession of a visa in accordance with Regulation (EC) No 539/2001, except where those persons hold a residence permit issued by a Member State or a residence permit issued by the United Kingdom or Ireland, in accordance with Directive 2004/38/EC of the European Parliament and of the Council of 29 April 2004 on the right of citizens of the Union and their family members to move and reside freely within the territory of the Member States ( 22 ).
> 2. A collective application for visas for the persons concerned shall be forwarded at the same time as applications for the issue of an Olympic accreditation card to the Organising Committee of the Member State hosting the Olympic and Paralympic Games in accordance with the procedure established by it.
> 3. Individual visa applications shall be submitted for each person taking part in the Olympic and/or Paralympic Games.
> 4. The Organising Committee of the Member State hosting the Olympic and Paralympic Games shall forward to the services responsible for issuing visas, a collective application for visas as quickly as possible, together with copies of applications for the issue of an Olympic accreditation card for the persons concerned, bearing their full name, nationality, sex and date and place of birth and the number, type and expiry date of their travel document.

Further:

> The visa issued shall be a uniform, multiple-entry visa authorising a stay of not more than 90 days for the duration of the Olympic and/or Paralympic Games.

Also, the visa isn't placed in the passport as visas normally are:

> The visa shall take the form of two numbers entered on the Olympic accreditation card. The first number shall be the visa number. In the case of a uniform visa, that number shall be made up of seven (7) characters comprising six (6) digits preceded by the letter ‘C’. In the case of a visa with limited territorial validity, that number shall be made up of eight (8) characters comprising six (6) digits preceded by the letters ‘XX’ (footnote 23). The second number shall be the number of the travel document of the person concerned.

Footnote 23 clarifies that "XX" refers to "the ISO code of the organising Member State."

Comment: (+1) Numerous French consulates also publish guidance making it explicit that participating in a competition is not considered work, even for professional athletes. For other sports-related travel, a permission from the relevant DIRECCTE might be necessary before applying for the Schengen visa.